# Logistic gradient Descent not converging in Python fmin_tnc

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I've been following a tutorial to implement logistic gradient descent in python. 
Here is the link:
http://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-3/


His ipython notebook github for this especific exercise here: 
https://github.com/jdwittenauer/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/ml/ML-Exercise2.ipynb


Here is my code for this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt  


def sigmoid(Z):
    '''Compute the sigmoid function '''
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp( -1.0 * Z))

###########################################


def compute_cost(theta,X,y, learningRate):
   '''compute cost given '''

    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = y.size
    theta0 = np.zeros((1,X.shape[1]))
    theta0[0,1:] = theta[0,1:]    

    reg = np.dot((learningRate/2*m),(theta0.T.dot(theta0))) 

    Z = X.dot(theta.T)

    hypothesis = sigmoid(Z)  
    exp1 = (-y.T.dot(np.log(hypothesis)))
    exp2 = ((1.0 - y).T.dot(np.log(1.0 - hypothesis)))    
    J = (exp1  - exp2).dot(1/m) 

    return J.sum() + reg.sum() 



def grad(theta,X,y,learningRate):    

    theta = theta.T          
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = y.shape[0]
    theta0 = np.zeros(X.shape[1])      
    theta0[1:] = theta[1:]    
    theta = np.matrix(theta)    
    theta0 = np.matrix(theta0)

    reg = np.dot(learningRate / m, theta)

    Z = X.dot(theta.T)    
    hypothesis = sigmoid(Z)      
    error = hypothesis - y        
    grad =  np.dot((X.T.dot(error).flatten()),1/m)  + reg
    grad= grad.flatten()  
    grad          

##
def predict(theta, X):    
    probability = sigmoid(X * theta.T)
    return [1 if (x >= 0.5) else 0 for x in probability]
```

Here is how the code is called :

    data2 = pd.read_csv('ex2data2.txt', header=None, names=['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Accepted'])

```
y = data2[data2.columns[-1]].as_matrix()
m = len(y)
y = y.reshape(m, 1)
X = data2[data2.columns[:-1]]
X = X.as_matrix()
_lambda = 1

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#Get all high order parameters
feature_mapper = PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)
X = feature_mapper.fit_transform(X)

# convert to numpy arrays and initalize the parameter array theta

theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

learningRate = 1

compute_cost(theta, X, y, learningRate)        

result = opt.fmin_tnc(func=compute_cost,x0=theta,fprime=grad,args=    (X,y,learningRate))
```

For one variable everything worked fine, but with more features( exercise 2) it did not work well. Everything until the optmized gradient descent function used(fmin_tnc) was exatcly the same.
Somehow even his code does not converge to the expected value. He it's his blog example showing what was supposed to be the result of fmin_tnc 
[image: his call and expected result for fmin_tnc]

But if you follow every step of his code you get the following result:
[image: Result giving by his code]

Well, as you can see it's a bit different. But I spotted a different thing in his code. He dropped 2 columns 'Test 1' and 'Test 2' and keep only the high order parameters. This feels strange because in Andrew Ng's solution he doesn't drop any column of the table, but he uses **28 features**. This one uses only **11 features**. I've found other codes, and I wanted my cost_function and gradient function to work. I believe they are getting stuck at some local minimum and they are not converging.

My final attempt I did with all 28 features just like Andrew's dataFrame. Sadly I've got a different result as you can see below:
[image: FInal Result]

As you can see, I've got a higher accuracy but my cost remains higher than the expected, which is : **0.52900** 
My intention is not to dimish the blog's code quality. I'm still following his steps on other tutorials and seems a good source.
Below is a link to my code, I'm using fmin_tnc just as he is doing. I just created a more vectorized gradient_function. The name of the file is Logistic Regression Regularized.py

Github: https://github.com/vinipachecov/Machine-Learning/tree/master/Logistic%20Regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using python 3.6 and the autor was using python 2.7.X. Changing the version to python 2.7.13 solved this issue.